# Visual Studio Code のTabの動作について

Tags: vscode

文章で説明しずらいのでスクリーンショットを取りました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

メモ帳に書いたものをvscodeに貼り付けただけです。
空白のところにはTabが一つ入っています。

vscodeではabcのインデントがずれてしまっています。
メモ帳と同じように揃うようにしたいのですが、
何か方法はありますでしょうか？

ちなみに自分のユーザー設定は下記になります。

```
{
    "files.encoding": "shiftjis",
    "editor.tabSize": 8,
    "editor.fontFamily": "MS Gothic",
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.insertSpaces": false
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

---

追記2018/3/22
Ver. 1.21.0で修正されたと思いましたが、残念ながらまだ解決に至ってないようです・・・
この画像のようにダッシュやスラッシュの全角だとまだインデントがズレてしまいます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

追記2018/7/10
久しぶりに確認してみましたが、Ver. 1.25.0でも依然とこの問題は解決されていません。
気になってしょうがないので自分でissue投稿してみました。
英語が合ってるか分かりませんが、これで何とかなると嬉しいです。
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53919

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 関連issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22832

Comment: 上記、リンクを見たら、　Milestone  Feb. 2018 になってますね。そろそろ、解決するのでしょうか?

Comment: Ver. 1.21.0　で修正の模様

Comment: まだ解決してなさそうです・・・追記させていただきました

Comment: issueの方、自分で投稿してみました。追記で公開しています。

Answer (score 2):

私も困っています。で、検索したら、こちらに来ました。
MSDNも聞いてみましたが、残念ながらでした。

内部Unicodeで処理しているためではないかと思いました。
タブ 8設定の場合、Asciiだろうが漢字だろうが、8文字単位で移動しているのでないかと。

直接、要望を(英文で)上げるか、自分でソースを修正するか、どちらかと半分諦めです。

ちなみに Visual Stdio だと、タブ文字を保持では、漢字一文字 ⇒ 半角2文字扱いでしたが、
スペースを挿入だと、こちらと同じ結果になるようです。

回答になってなく申し訳ありませんが、参考までに。

---

2018.3.10 追記
**Ver. 1.21.0 で修正**されたようです。リリースノートでは確認出ませんでしたが、手元で確認した範囲では OKでした。

---

2018.3.22 追記
**Ver. 1.21.0 で修正されたがまだ一部に問題が残っている**ようです。
確認したものは質問の方に追記させていただきましたので、そちらをご覧ください。
英語ぜんぜん出来ませんがissueに載せてみようかなと思い始めています。

---

2018.4.16 追記
**Ver. 1.22.2** では以下のようになりました。

[image: Ver. 1.22.2 での結果]

バージョンアップがあったので、どうなるかと思いましたが、、、。
別にあら探しするつもりは無かったのですが、最初に "きごう" と入力して変換、Tabの結果です。なかなか大変みたいですね。

Comment: 質問にコメントする形にしましたが、既に vscode の issue として挙がっています。 https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22832

Comment: 自分でもいろいろ調べましたが、薄々そんな感じかと思っていました。VSCode個人的には好きなんですけどここだけ残念ですね。ありがとうございました。また何かいい方法があったら報告しようと思います。

Comment: Ver. 1.21.0 で修正されたがまだ一部に問題が残っているようです。
確認したものは質問の方に追記させていただきましたので、そちらをご覧ください。
英語ぜんぜん出来ませんがissueに載せてみようかなと思い始めています。